# How to read names of files stored in IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have some files which are stored in IsolatedStorage. The files are of different types. I need to get names of all the files. How can I read the file names from IsolatedStorage. Only file name is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `GetFileNames` method. If you only want the names of all the files in the root of IsolatedStorage, you could

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames();
}
```

If you want the names of the files inside other directories too, you could use `GetDirectoryNames` method to get all the directory names to retrieve names of all the directories at root level.

`GetFileNames` and `GetDirectoryNames` also have overloaded methods which take a search pattern string and return the names of all the files/directories that match the pattern.

So, in order to get names of files inside some directory, you could

```
string searchPattern = directory + "\\*";
string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames(searchPattern);
```

This will give you the names of all the files stored in the `directory` directory.

`GetDirectoryNames` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190673.aspx

`GetFileNames` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getfilenames%28v=vs.95%29.aspx