# Creating files programmatically and getting the file names from WP7 isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an app which requires saving a form whenever user enter the details. I want each form to be stored in separate .dat file. Using GUID as file names, I am able to store the data in separate files now. But I am not able to retrieve all the filenames and bind it to a listbox of hyperlinkbutton, on click of which will show all the data stored in the particular file. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to have a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190395(v=vs.95).aspx

"GetFileNames" is a method of "IsolatedStorageFile" which shows all the files in the directory it is pointing to.

In this question you can get an example:
[How to read names of files stored in IsolatedStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967263/how-to-read-names-of-files-stored-in-isolatedstorage)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [GetFilesNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190395%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method of your [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getuserstoreforapplication%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Use a wildcard (*.dat) to retrieve a list of your files.

For example:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    string pattern = "*.dat";
    string[] files = store.GetFileNames(pattern);
}
```